# How do I combine multiple pandas dataframes into an HDF5 object under one key/group?

Tags: pandas, hdf5, dask, pytables, hdfstore

I am parsing data from a large csv sized 800 GB. For each line of data, I save this as a pandas dataframe.

```
readcsvfile = csv.reader(csvfile)
for i, line in readcsvfile:
    # parse create dictionary of key:value pairs by csv field:value, "dictionary_line"
    # save as pandas dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary_line, index=[i])
```

Now, I would like to save this into an HDF5 format, and query the h5 as if it was the entire csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
store = pd.HDFStore("pathname/file.h5")

hdf5_key = "single_key"

csv_columns = ["COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4",..., "COL55"]
```

My approach so far has been:

```
import pandas as pd
store = pd.HDFStore("pathname/file.h5")

hdf5_key = "single_key"

csv_columns = ["COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4",..., "COL55"]
readcsvfile = csv.reader(csvfile)
for i, line in readcsvfile:
    # parse create dictionary of key:value pairs by csv field:value, "dictionary_line"
    # save as pandas dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary_line, index=[i])
    store.append(hdf5_key, df, data_columns=csv_columns, index=False)
```

That is, I try to save each dataframe `df` into the HDF5 under one key. However, this fails:

```
  Attribute 'superblocksize' does not exist in node: '/hdf5_key/_i_table/index'
```

So, I could try to save everything into one pandas dataframe first, i.e.

```
import pandas as pd
store = pd.HDFStore("pathname/file.h5")

hdf5_key = "single_key"

csv_columns = ["COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4",..., "COL55"]
readcsvfile = csv.reader(csvfile)
total_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i, line in readcsvfile:
    # parse create dictionary of key:value pairs by csv field:value, "dictionary_line"
    # save as pandas dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary_line, index=[i])
    total_df = pd.concat([total_df, df])   # creates one big CSV
```

and now store into HDF5 format

```
    store.append(hdf5_key, total_df, data_columns=csv_columns, index=False)
```

However, I don't think I have the RAM/storage to save all csv lines into `total_df` into HDF5 format.

So, how do I append each "single-line" df into an HDF5 so that it ends up as one big dataframe (like the original csv)?

EDIT: Here's a concrete example of a csv file with different data types:

```
 order    start    end    value    
 1        1342    1357    category1
 1        1459    1489    category7
 1        1572    1601    category23
 1        1587    1599    category2
 1        1591    1639    category1
 ....
 15        792     813    category13
 15        892     913    category5
 ....
```

Comment: Are even all entries of the same type? IRC, hdf5 doesn't do mixed arrays.

Comment: @Paul Well, how do you place an entire +TB csv datatable into HDF5 format?

Comment: @MaxU I know you are an HDF5 expert. Is this possible? It feels like a very simple task...

Comment: @Paul Should I create individual columns for each csv field COL1, COL2, .. and append values there from the dictionary/from the pandas dataframe? How would I deal with 'NaN' values? What do you reommend?

Comment: @Ümit You are also a renowned HDF5 expert on StackOverlow---surely this is a simple task, right? Should I somehow save each of the field values into separate arrays, and then save into HDF5? (I don't know whether this would preserve the csv "dataframe" structure, and I worry I will run into RAM issues saving huge arrays before storing into HDF5...)

Comment: can you show some lines of the csv file?

Comment: @HYRY I added an example above of a csv with multiple columns and different datatypes.

Comment: Why don't you use `pandas.read_csv()` with `chunksize` argument?

Comment: @HYRY I need to do a good deal of "clean-up" for each line. That's why I'm parsing this extensively (not all details shown above for clarity---this is technically tab-delimited data, not exactly a cleaned-up csv file). Let's try this: what would be the easiest way to replicate what `pandas.read_csv()` does and save the parsed csv lines into HDF5 by chunks? You parse 10,000 lines, save to HDF5 under one group/key, and continue.

Comment: `store.append()` should work, can you post some test data and test code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @HYRY It should basically be the third code block above. I get the error `Attribute 'superblocksize' does not exist in node: '/hdf5_key/_i_table/index'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work, can you try the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

store = pd.HDFStore("file.h5", "w")
hdf5_key = "single_key"
csv_columns = ["COL%d" % i for i in range(1, 56)]
for i in range(10):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1, len(csv_columns)), columns=csv_columns)
    store.append(hdf5_key, df,  data_column=csv_columns, index=False)
store.close()
```

If the code works, then there are something wrong with your data.

Comment: This code certain does work---but I'm not sure what could be "wrong" with my data. I get either two errors: `Attribute 'superblocksize' does not exist in node: '/hdf5_key/_i_table/index'` or `ValueError: cannot match existing table structure for [COLl1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, ...] on appending data`

Comment: Actually, the reason this example works and mine throws the error `ValueError: cannot match existing table structure for [COLl1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, ...] on appending data` appears to be that my data has multiple types. How would you do the above if the columns of `df` had strings, integers, floats, etc. ?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang If you have a column with both string and numbers, convert all of the valuess to string or number first.