# HDF5 min_itemsize error: ValueError: Trying to store a string with len [##] in [y] column but this column has a limit of [##]!

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables, hdfstore

I am getting the following error after using `pandas.HDFStore().append()`

```
ValueError: Trying to store a string with len [150] in [values_block_0] column but  this column has a limit of [127]!

Consider using min_itemsize to preset the sizes on these columns
```

I am creating a pandas DataFrame and appending it to the HDF5 file as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

store = pd.HDFStore("test1.h5", mode='w')

hdf_key = "one_key"

columns = ["col1", "col2", ... ]

df = pd.Dataframe(...)
df.col1 = df.col1.astype(str)
df.col2 = df.col2astype(int)
df.col3 = df.col3astype(str)
.... 
store.append(hdf_key, df, data_column=columns, index=False)
```

I get the error above: "ValueError: Trying to store a string with len [150] in [values_block_0] column but  this column has a limit of [127]!"

Afterwards, I execute the code:

```
store.get_storer(hdf_key).table.description
```

which outputs

```
{
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "values_block_0": StringCol(itemsize=127, shape=(5,), dflt=b'', pos=1),
  "values_block_1": Int64Col(shape=(5,), dflt=0, pos=2),
  "col1": StringCol(itemsize=20, shape=(), dflt=b'', pos=3),
  "col2": StringCol(itemsize=39, shape=(), dflt=b'', pos=4)}
```

What are `values_block_0` and `values_block_1`?

So, following this StackOverflow [Pandas pytable: how to specify min_itemsize of the elements of a MultiIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710738/pandas-pytable-how-to-specify-min-itemsize-of-the-elements-of-a-multiindex) , I tried

```
store.append(hdf_key, df, data_column=columns, index=False,  min_itemsize={"values_block_0":250})
```

This doesn't work though---now I get this error:

```
ValueError: Trying to store a string with len [250] in [values_block_0] column but  this column has a limit of [127]!

Consider using min_itemsize to preset the sizes on these columns
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This code produces the error `ValueError: min_itemsize has the key [values_block_0] which is not an axis or data_column` from `filename.py`

```
import pandas as pd
store = pd.HDFStore("test1.h5", mode='w')
hdf_key = "one_key"

my_columns = ["col1", "col2", ... ]

df = pd.Dataframe(...)
df.col1 = df.col1.astype(str)
df.col2 = df.col2astype(int)
df.col3 = df.col3astype(str)
.... 
store.append(hdf_key, df, data_column=my_columns, index=False, min_itemsize={"values_block_0":350})
```

Here is the full error:

```
(python-3) -bash:1008 $ python filename.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filename.py", line 50, in <module>
    store.append(hdf_key, dicts_into_df,  data_column=my_columns, index=False, min_itemsize={'values_block_0':350})
  File "/path/lib/python-3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 970, in append
    **kwargs)
  File "/path/lib/python-3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 1315, in _write_to_group
    s.write(obj=value, append=append, complib=complib, **kwargs)
  File "/path/lib/python-3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 4263, in write
    obj=obj, data_columns=data_columns, **kwargs)
  File "/path/lib/python-3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 3853, in write
    **kwargs)
  File "/path/lib/python-3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 3535, in create_axes
    self.validate_min_itemsize(min_itemsize)
  File "/path/lib/python-3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 3174, in validate_min_itemsize
    "data_column" % k)
ValueError: min_itemsize has the key [values_block_0] which is not an axis or data_column
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

you have misspelled `data_columns` parameter: `data_column` - it should be `data_columns`. As a result you didn't have any indexed columns in your HDF Store and HDF store added `values_block_X`:

```
In [70]: store = pd.HDFStore(r'D:\temp\.data\my_test.h5')
```

misspelled parameters will be ignored:

```
In [71]: store.append('no_idx_wrong_dc', df, data_column=df.columns, index=False)

In [72]: store.get_storer('no_idx_wrong_dc').table
Out[72]:
/no_idx_wrong_dc/table (Table(10,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "values_block_0": Float64Col(shape=(1,), dflt=0.0, pos=1),
  "values_block_1": Int64Col(shape=(1,), dflt=0, pos=2),
  "values_block_2": StringCol(itemsize=30, shape=(1,), dflt=b'', pos=3)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (1213,)
```

is the same as the following:

```
In [73]: store.append('no_idx_no_dc', df, index=False)

In [74]: store.get_storer('no_idx_no_dc').table
Out[74]:
/no_idx_no_dc/table (Table(10,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "values_block_0": Float64Col(shape=(1,), dflt=0.0, pos=1),
  "values_block_1": Int64Col(shape=(1,), dflt=0, pos=2),
  "values_block_2": StringCol(itemsize=30, shape=(1,), dflt=b'', pos=3)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (1213,)
```

let's spell it correctly:

```
In [75]: store.append('no_idx_dc', df, data_columns=df.columns, index=False)

In [76]: store.get_storer('no_idx_dc').table
Out[76]:
/no_idx_dc/table (Table(10,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "value": Float64Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=1),
  "count": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=2),
  "s": StringCol(itemsize=30, shape=(), dflt=b'', pos=3)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (1213,)
```

**OLD Answer:**

AFAIK you can **effectively** set the `min_itemsize` parameter **on the first** append only.

Demo:

```
In [33]: df
Out[33]:
   num                 s
0   11  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
1   12    bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
2   13     ccccccccccccc
3   14       ddddddddddd

In [34]: store = pd.HDFStore(r'D:\temp\.data\my_test.h5')

In [35]: store.append('test_1', df, data_columns=True)

In [36]: store.get_storer('test_1').table.description
Out[36]:
{
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "num": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=1),
  "s": StringCol(itemsize=16, shape=(), dflt=b'', pos=2)}

In [37]: df.loc[4] = [15, 'X'*200]

In [38]: df
Out[38]:
   num                                                  s
0   11                                   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
1   12                                     bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
2   13                                      ccccccccccccc
3   14                                        ddddddddddd
4   15  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...

In [39]: store.append('test_1', df, data_columns=True)
...
skipped
...
ValueError: Trying to store a string with len [200] in [s] column but
this column has a limit of [16]!
Consider using min_itemsize to preset the sizes on these columns
```

now using `min_itemsize`, but still appending to the existing `store` object:

```
In [40]: store.append('test_1', df, data_columns=True, min_itemsize={'s':250})
...
skipped
...
ValueError: Trying to store a string with len [250] in [s] column but
this column has a limit of [16]!
Consider using min_itemsize to preset the sizes on these columns
```

The following works if we will create a new object in our `store`:

```
In [41]: store.append('test_2', df, data_columns=True, min_itemsize={'s':250})
```

Check column sizes:

```
In [42]: store.get_storer('test_2').table.description
Out[42]:
{
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "num": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=1),
  "s": StringCol(itemsize=250, shape=(), dflt=b'', pos=2)}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am still slightly confused how to implement this solution when iterating through multiple dataframes and appending? `for chunk in pd.csv_reader(): store.append(key, chunk, data_columns)` or `for i in range: df=pd.Dataframe(); store.append(key, chunk, data_columns)` like answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925077/how-do-i-combine-multiple-pandas-dataframes-into-an-hdf5-object-under-one-key-gr

It appears you run the script. If there's an error, `store.append` on a new key.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, you either need to know the maximum length of the `values_block_0` column or use a value which will for sure be able to hold the max. length, for example: `min_itemsize={"values_block_0":1000}`

Comment: The problem with this approach (i.e. using `min_itemsize={"values_block_0":1000}`) is I get this error: `ValueError: min_itemsize has the key [values_block_0] which is not an axis or data_column`. Only after the first error is raised `ValueError: Trying to store a string with len [200] in [values_block_0] column but this column has a limit of [16]!` does it appears that `values_block_0` is recognized as a column

Comment: should I be using a different value than `value_block_0`?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, can you post a code producing `ValueError: min_itemsize has the key [values_block_0] which is not an axis or data_column`?

Comment: Edite the above. I could send you the actual script, but that's basically it.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, it means that your `dicts_into_df` DF doesn't have `values_block_0` at the moment you call `store.append(...)`

Comment: I see. So, this should be named first?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, your DF should have a column that you are specifying in the `min_itemsize` parameter

Comment: It isn't a column that I have provided. I have edited the above. Could you explain to me what `values_block_0` and `values_block_1` are? These values are not columns within the dataframe `df`

Comment: This works. Silly mistake of mine. Thank you! However, there is still an issue that if you define the `min_itemsize` for each column, the could be a `ValueError` on the first append, like `ValueError: min_itemsize has the key [col_20] which is not an axis or data_column`. I'm guessing this is before this column is read? It must be considered a column as it is included in `data_columns`

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, i think i've answered your original question. Please open a new one as your question and my answer are already pretty overloaded...

Comment: Yes, you answered this. Thanks! I was clarifying a pandas functional issue. Thank you! I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

I started to get this error around about the same time as updating Pandas from 18.1 to 22.0 (although this could be unrelated).

I fixed the error in the existing HDF5 file by manually reading the dataframe in, then writing a new HDF5 file with a larger `min_itemsize` for the column mentioned in the error:

```
filename_hdf5 = "C:\test.h5"
df = pd.read_hdf(filename_hdf5, 'table_name')
hdf = HDFStore(filename_hdf5)
hdf.put('table_name', df, format='table', data_columns=True, min_itemsize={'ColumnNameMentionedInError': 10})
hdf.close()
```

I then updated the existing code to set `min_itemsize` on key creation.

---

#### Extra for Experts

The error occurs because one is trying to append more rows to an existing dataframe with a fixed column width too narrow for the new data. The fixed column width was originally set based on the longest string in the column when the dataframe was first written.

Methinks that pandas should handle this error transparently, rather than leaving what is effectively a timebomb for all future appends. This issue could take weeks or even years to surface.